# Sort by comment?

Tags: finder, metadata, sort

I have started setting deadlines on a document by putting the date in the comments, using the YYYY-MM-DD format and then what type of deadline it is (I have to submit initial, interim, and discharge reports).

It would be helpful if I could sort by comments so it would be in order. Is there any simple way to do this? Currently it seems that the only sorting options are name, kind, date, size, and tag.

I'd be open to a third party app if there is a good one that adds this function to the finder.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a more elegant way, but this works:

Open finder, and search for 'foo'. Once the search starts, click the + on the far right

(the lower one :-):

[image: click +]

then, on the dropdown on the left scroll down to 'other', and in the popup, scroll to 'Comment', and select 'in Menu':

[image: Comment in menu]

At this point, you can right click your headings, and add the 'Comment' field, and sort by it. You can also do searches where Comment [contains, starts with, etc].

In addition to adding the comments column, you can select 'Raw Query' and make more complicated searches like:

```
kMDItemFinderComment=2020-08* && ......
```

You can save these searches as 'Smart Folders', and refer back to them as needed. See [this page](https://www.macworld.com/article/3264653/macos-how-to-use-spotlights-query-language-to-create-an-all-my-files-like-feature.html) for more tips.

Comment: The Finder search for Comment (and the column Content) are based on the metadata kMDItemComment.  The OP is most likely using the Comments panel in Finder Info - that goes onto kMDItemFinderComment.  The latter requires the search field Spotlight Comment and whilst I can search on it, I can't use it as a column header.

Answer (score -3):

You could use Numbers and put the info in different columns. One column for date, a column for type and a third column for all the rest. Then you can sort your data according to column 1. This will make it simple to add more data and to keep track of your info.

Comment: What would you do to get the file names and the comments into Numbers?